# Где можно начать изучать React

Tags: reactjs

Есть какие-то гайды по React или что-нибудь на подобие того. Просто хочется именно читать, а не смотреть какие-то видеокурсы

Comment: Есть. [Этого](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=книги+по+реакт&clid=2270455&banerid=6400000000%3ASW-92d10c848ef0&win=621&from=omb&lr=116394) достаточно?)

Comment: https://react.dev/ - официальная документация. 100500 примеров и если нужно, то есть более углублённая информация. Знаю, что обычно официальные документации не отличаются своей читабельностью, но тут не так (по крайней мере ддля меня)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте читать этот [сайт](https://ru.react.js.org/docs). Это просто документация... Но думаю вы не запутаетесь

Comment: Плохая идея начинать изучать язык (или фреймворк) с документации. Запутаться как раз таки можно "на ура".

Comment: Старая документация...